# Short delay after UIAlertView dismissed on iOS 7

Tags: ios, delay, uialertview, lag, dismiss

I noticed that after dismiss a `UIAlertView`, there is a short amount of time that apps do not recognize any touches.
So, I made a very simple project, which only contains 2 `UIButton`s (one to change a `label` to a random number and one to show a `UIAlertView`).

Tested it both on device (an iPhone4) and simulator (iOS 6 and iOS 7).
The result is this lag only happens on iOS 7. On iOS 6.x, it works just fine.

The delay duration depends on how large the app is. In the test project, which I described above, the delay is about 0.3s. However, in an another project of mine, it maybe up to 1 second.

I also used `GCD`, follow this:

```
- (void) startSomeLongOperation {
   //display alertView
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0), ^{
       // …do something that takes long…
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //dismiss alertView
       });
   });
}
```

another one I have tried:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //show and dismiss alertView      
 });
```

neither of them work.

So, I jumped in to conclusion that this delay was caused by iOS 7.

Have anyone experienced this before ?

Comment: Have you tried dispatching it another queue? Have you logged the time elapsed at each point along the way? I don't have my Mac with me but I would try these to see if there is any difference where the time goes

Comment: thank you. I'm new to iOS development, don't know how to do what you asked.

Comment: I am just throwing stuff out there, I don't know that it would make any difference... so instead of using `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0)` you could make a new queue `queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);` from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html and then use that as the queue

Comment: And just adding a `NSLog("Entered ...")` after each entry point to see when each step got run

Comment: I tried, it doesn't change anything. The `[alert show]` is still executed at the end of code block (not sure if i'm doing it right or not ?). However, theoretically, after `alertView` was dismissed, it shouldn't block anything at all, and that was true on iOS 6.x. So if this was an error on iOS7, we can't do anything about it, right ?